# Why is the following function entire?

Tags: entire-functions

While learning about entire (complex) functions, I had to prove why the following function is entire (or in other words, prove that it is holomorphic for all complex $z$):

$f(z) =\frac{\sqrt3\cos(z)}{z^4} -\frac{\sin (z\sqrt3)}{z^5}$

This is not evident to me, as I would think there is a singularity for $z=0$. My teacher stated that $f(z)$ is entire, whereas Mathematica suggests that the function is not entire. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you determine the behavior at $z=0$?  If a function is analytic in a punctured neighborhood of $0$ and bounded there, then it is analytic even at $0$ (extends uniquely).

Comment: Write the Taylor series for $z\sqrt 3 \cos z- \sin(\sqrt 3 z)$ and note that it is $z^5f(z)$ so the ratio is entire

Comment: Thanks all! Didn't see that at once, it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be clear that the function is holomorphic outside $z = 0$.

Now at $z = 0$, you should expand it in Laurent series. This will look like:
$$f(z) = \sqrt{3}z^{-4}(1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - \cdots) - z^{-5}(\sqrt{3}z - \frac{(\sqrt{3}z)^3}{3!} + \frac{(\sqrt{3}z)^5}{5!} - \cdots).
$$

You will see that the negative powers of $z$ are cancelled. So indeed $f$ is entire.